# Trying to remove a tick label in dimple.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I've built a line-graph in dimple.js that can be found here. http://jsfiddle.net/lukehtravis/0twgc2uL/

You'll notice on the y-axis, there is a little "m" that is automatically generated by dimple and placed next to the numbers as a quantity label.

I combed through the documentation, but couldn't find anything about that little m.

Anyone know how to remove it? Here's the code

```
            // Create the canvas to draw on
            var svg = d3.select("#charty")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 800)
                .attr("height", 500);

            // Create the chart object | contents of data visible in fiddle link above
            var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);

            //Create the x axis
            var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Day");
            x.showGridlines = true;

            // Create the y axis
            var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Volume");
            y.title = "Volume (AF)";
            y.overrideMin = 300000;
            y.overrideMax = 1450000;
            y.showGridlines = true;

            // Add location as data series
            var series = chart.addSeries("Location", dimple.plot.line);

            // Decorate the lines in the graph
            series.lineWeight = 2;
            series.lineMarkers = true;

            // Create the legend
            chart.addLegend(100, 50, 200, 200);

            // Draw the chart
            chart.draw(3100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small m is not but conversion of units into million..

0.3million is your value 300000 .. Its pretty normal and not an error ..

If you dont want that then just add this line  `y.tickFormat = "1f";` after

```
y.showGridlines = true;
```